# Differences between handling errors with window.onerror and try-catch block

Tags: javascript

I am considering handling JavaScript runtime errors with `window.onerror` vs. `try{...} catch(e){...}` blocks.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror states:

> Note that some/many error events do not trigger window.onerror, you have to listen for them specifically.

It seems that both `window.onerror` and `try{...} catch(e){...}`can handle ReferenceError: http://jsfiddle.net/7RARf/

Also, both are incapable of handling SyntaxError: http://jsfiddle.net/UXVs2/

Apart from obvious differences between handling error using `window.onerror` and handling them `try{...} catch(e){...}` with like, try-catch allows us to handle an error gracefully, re-throw them, etc. whereas a window.onerror function does not, etc. what other differences exist between the two ways of handling errors? Are there any errors that can be handled with `window.onerror` but not with `try{...} catch(e){...}`? Vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - window.onerror can detect errors caused by browser workflow - try/catch operates only on limited part of executed js code. window.onerror may detect plugins issues or any errors caused by not strictly your code (libraries like jQ, APIs like YT API etc) - eg: you can't put asynchronous code supported by external library in try (without modifications in foreign code), you can't put script loading done by html  tag into try (it's managed by browser) - window.onerror will fire when script file is damaged and can't be loaded to  tag - window.onerror throws much more errors than catch is able to support - also it contains info about file and line. Disadvantage is that window.onerror gives only info - code is interrupted, using try/catch you can provide fallback behaviour and allow code to deal with situation - even if there were errors

you can use try/catch to catch syntax error but only if you're evaluating code form string :

```
try{
  eval('(function(){asdhaowd;;;;asd;!!!@#!@$lolzolololol]]]]]]]})()');
} catch(e){
  do sth();
}
```

It'll catch eval error (unexpected ']' or something before it)
I'm using it on my site to detect damaged code uploaded by users.
window.onerror is usefull only for debug - it can't prevent code from crash, when try can

Comment: If you're putting try - you probably expect error to happen - window.onerror is usefull for tracking unexpected bugs in code - eg. you can bind function sending error reports to your mail

Answer (score 0):

window.onerror is like a global try/catch block.  Use try/catch to target specific blocks where you know you are likely to get an error.

the window.onerror is a general case.  One thing I noticed is that the function you assign to window.onerror to handle the error, should be defined above the code that calls it or you might get a function undefined error.